# Finding an eigenvector given other eigenvectors for JNF

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I want to find the Jordan Normal Form of the matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
                19 & -7 & -1 & 5 & -7 \\
                3 & 9 & -1 & 3 & -5 \\
                -10 & 14 & 16 & -10 & 14 \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 14 & 0 \\
                2 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 12
            \end{pmatrix}.$$
I am given that it has the following pair of rank two generalised eigenvectors:
$$ \mathbf x_2=\begin{pmatrix}
                1\\-1\\0\\-2\\0
            \end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad  \mathbf y_2=\begin{pmatrix}
                2\\0\\1\\0\\1
        \end{pmatrix},$$
and that its characteristic polynomial is $(x-14)^5$.

The fact that they are rank two means they generate two others, namely $\mathbf x_1 = ( M-14I)\mathbf x_2$ and $\mathbf y_1 = (M-14I)\mathbf y_2$.  So if I define the matrix $P = (\mathbf x_1 \mid \mathbf x_2\mid\mathbf y_1\mid\mathbf y_2\mid\mathbf z)$, then we have that
$$P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix}
14 & 1\\
& 14 \\
& & 14 & 1\\
& & & 14 \\
&&&&14
\end{pmatrix},$$
but I still need to find the vector $\mathbf z$ for this to work. Is there some efficient way I can compute it, given what I know already? or do I have to go through the whole usual computation of finding eigenvectors?

I appreciate any help with this.